# R Studio error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr, anova

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "ggpubr", "tidyverse", "broom", "AICcmodavg", "dplyr"))
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(AICcmodavg)

library(dplyr)

my_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                      sep = "\t", header=TRUE)


group_by(my_data, group) %>%
  suppressWarnings(as.numeric(co2))  
***dplyr::summarise (count = dplyr::n(), mean = dplyr::mean("CO2", na.rm = TRUE),sd = dplyr::sd("CO2", na.rm = TRUE))***
```

Working towards a one-way ANOVA test on some data I have for my dissertation but the last line (marked with *** above ***) keeps returning the following error code:

***Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.***

What could be going wrong?
Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Do you get the same error when you don't include `dplyr::` in front of the function calls? It is unnecessary here because you loaded `tidyverse`.

Comment: After the `group_by`, there are multiple expressions.  Perhaps you need `mutate(co2 = as.numeric(co2)) %>% summarise(count = n(), ...`

Comment: Removing the dplyr doesn't stop the error- I added this to try and fix the problem as I found on another forum, but the error code remains with my original code:

Comment: ~~~group_by(my_data, group) %>%
mutate(co2 = as.numeric(co2)) %>% 
suppressWarnings(as.numeric(co2))~~~ Would this be appropriate placing? The error seems to persist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is admittedly a little bit opaque, but we can replicate it as simply as

```r
summarise(count = n())
```

Since you haven't piped the results of the first few lines to the final `summarise()`, your `summarise()` call is essentially being read as a standalone function, with a missing `data` argument (`summarise(mtcars, count = n())` works OK).

You might be looking for a pipeline like this (illustrated with built-in data set `mtcars`):

```r
library(tidyverse)
group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
  mutate(across(mpg, as.numeric)) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
            mean = mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd = sd(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)
           )
```

By the way, if you're doing an ANOVA you probably don't want to collapse the data to summary statistics first (unless someone is making you do the computations by hand); `anova(lm(...))` is more natural, where you apply the `lm()` to non-aggregated data.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have solved the problem!

Comment: if the answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.