# No applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "ts"

Tags: r, anova

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "ggpubr", "tidyverse", "broom", "AICcmodavg"))
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(AICcmodavg)
               
my_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                      sep = "\t", header=TRUE)

group_by(my_data, group) %>%
mutate(across(co2, as.numeric)) %>% 
suppressWarnings(as.numeric(co2))
summarise (co2, count = n(), mean = mean("CO2", na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd("CO2", na.rm = TRUE))
```

Working my way towards carrying out a one way anova test with a dataset and I keep getting this same error code:

No applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "ts"

When I run the following line of code:

```
summarise (co2, count = n(), mean = mean("CO2", na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd("CO2", na.rm = TRUE))
```

My dataset involves no timeseries (a table of CO2 emissions compared to vegetation type) so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and what I can do to solve it?
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Isn't this similar to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010647/r-studio-error-n-must-only-be-used-inside-dplyr-verbs)

Comment: Where does your `co2` Object come from? What have you tried in the 45 minutes or so since your last question? It’s unlikely that a string as a first argument to a summary function (eg `mean`) is correct.  It’s bad to use the name of a function (eg `mean`) as an object or column name.

Comment: My CO2 object comes from a separate excel sheet. My only real change is the addition of this line- mutate(across(co2, as.numeric)) %>%  - which solved the previous error but created this new one immediately! So far I'm just working through applying the suggestions made in the recommended other post (summarise monthly seasonal factors) to see if that helps. What would you recommend changing the first argument to? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This seems like a typo—did you mean to have a pipe going into your `summarise` call? It's hard to know for sure without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862). The `suppressWarnings` line doesn't make sense either, since you probably meant for that to be inside the `mutate` call

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three problems with your code:

1. This code is meaningless:

   ```r
   ... %>% 
     suppressWarnings(as.numeric(co2))
   ```

   This call to `suppressWarnings` really evaluates to

   ```r
   ... %>% 
     suppressWarnings(., as.numeric(co2))
   ```

   which argument-expands to

   ```r
   ... %>% 
     suppressWarnings(expr = ., classes = as.numeric(co2))
   ```

   which ... does absolutely nothing. Fortunately, it passes the frame passed to it with no change, so it will not *error* ... but it also does absolutely nothing to the data, including what you may have originally intended with `as.numeric(.)`. If you want to convert `co2` to numeric from something else, this should likely be

   ```r
   ... %>% 
     mutate(co2 = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(co2)))
   ```

   However ... that seems completely redundant given that the line before that is `mutate(across(co2, as.numeric))`, which does precisely that.
2. Because you do not continue the pipeline from the `suppressWarnings(.)` line, your next call is

   ```r
   summarise (co2, ...)
   ```

   If you had differently-named variables, this should fail with `object 'somethingelse' not found`, but you used `co2`. That *happens* to be the name of `co2` in the `datasets` package, which is *not* a `data.frame`, it is class `ts`. Type in `?co2` to see what that data is about, and just `co2` to see what you were really passing there.

   Fix this problem by adding `%>%` to the previous line. Actually, removing the previous line (and using the fact that the *previous* previous line does have the `%>%`), it may be something like:

   ```r
   group_by(my_data, group) %>%
     mutate(across(co2, as.numeric)) %>% 
     summarise(...)
   ```

   For efficiency, though, doing that `mutate` within a grouping is inefficient. I suggest instead:

   ```r
   my_data %>%
     mutate(across(co2, ~ suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.)))) %>%
     group_by(group) %>%
     summarise(...)
   ```
3. Your `summarise` call is confuses me.

   ```r
   summarise(
     co2,
     count = n(),
     mean = mean("CO2", na.rm = TRUE),
     sd = sd("CO2", na.rm = TRUE)
   )
   ```

   - `co2`, assuming it is really a column in the data, will "summarise" to the same number of rows with no aggregation of `co2`. Perhaps this should be some aggregating function, like `min` or `max`? I'll remove this from my suggested code below.
   - `count = n()` makes sense, but it returns a single number, so when combined with `co2` above, it will repeat this one number `nrow(.)` times. When we remove `co2` above, this will be fine.
   - `mean = mean("CO2", na.rm=TRUE)` ... what is the average of a *string*? Do you mean `mean = mean(co2, na.rm=TRUE)`?
   - `sd = sd("CO2", na.rm=TRUE)` ... ditto.

Ultimately, try this:

```r
my_data %>%
  mutate(across(co2, ~ suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.)))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(co2, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(co2, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you that's done the trick! Thank you for the patience- R is very new to me!